# What is wrong with my constraints in auto layout scroll view?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am having an extremely difficult time trying to fix my auto layout for a scrollView. I made sure that there is a content view under the scrollView and made the content view to have equal width and height with the mainView. But when I run the app, only the main view (superview) appears. To illustrate my situation better, I have the following screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You can't constraint the contents of UIScrollView with AutoLayout constraints. It doesn't work.

Comment: @Fogmeister How can I apply constraints to the contents of UIScrollView?

Comment: The same problem occurred to me. I think, there is some kind of bug. I solved it by clearing all constraints and then manually assign constraint to each UI object. If you auto assign the constraints, some views disappear.

Comment: See Technical Note TN2154 UIScrollView And Autolayout https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html

Comment: @MaxMacLeod How will this work with storyboard though?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it in code:

### ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *contentView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *toolBoxView;

@end
```

### ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self initViews];
    [self initConstraints];
}

-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    // This line is required to prevent text label from
    // forcing scrollView to be horizontally format
    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    self.toolBoxView.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width - 40.0;
}

-(void)initViews
{
    self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    self.scrollView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    self.scrollView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;

    self.contentView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    self.contentView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    self.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;

    self.toolBoxView = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    self.toolBoxView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
    self.toolBoxView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    self.toolBoxView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.toolBoxView.text = @"This is the toolbox view. Which resides within the contentView of a UIScrollView. The scrollView will adjust to fit the content of the text within this toolBoxView. Feel free to change this text as you see fit\n\nThis is the toolbox view. Which resides within the contentView of a UIScrollView. The scrollView will adjust to fit the content of the text within this toolBoxView. Feel free to change this text as you see fit\n\nThis is the toolbox view. Which resides within the contentView of a UIScrollView. The scrollView will adjust to fit the content of the text within this toolBoxView. Feel free to change this text as you see fit\n\nThis is the toolbox view. Which resides within the contentView of a UIScrollView. The scrollView will adjust to fit the content of the text within this toolBoxView. Feel free to change this text as you see fit\n\n";
    self.toolBoxView.numberOfLines = 0;
    self.toolBoxView.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;



    [self.contentView addSubview:self.toolBoxView];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.contentView];

    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
}

-(void)initConstraints
{
    self.scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.toolBoxView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    id views = @{
                 @"scrollView": self.scrollView,
                 @"contentView": self.contentView,
                 @"toolBoxView": self.toolBoxView
                 };

    // scrollView constraints

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];



    // contentView constraints (need to pin to all four sides of scrollView)

    [self.scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[contentView]-10-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self.scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[contentView]-10-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];


    // toolBoxView constraints

    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[toolBoxView]-10-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[toolBoxView]-10-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
}
```

This is what I get:

[image: screenshot]

The really weird thing is, why Xcode doesn't say there's an autolayout conflict, because if you look at my above code, I've pinned scrollView's four edges to viewController's view BUT at the same time, contentView is strongly pinned to all four edges of scrollView and toolBoxView is also strongly pinned to contentView's edges. Theoretically if toolBoxView is shorter or taller than scrollView it would result in a conflict.

I guess this is how UIScrollView works in autolayout.

If I change:

```
V:|[scrollView]|
```

to

```
V:|[scrollView]
```

I just see a blank white page (i.e. what you describe as "only main view appears").

Hopefully the above constraints I've written can help you debug your Interface Builder constraints, maybe you can compare yours to mine.

Hope that helps.